# Converted to Float and Int, TypeError: can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'float' Python 2.7

Tags: python, python-2.7, csv

I am trying to open a CSV file, iterate over its row's and convert the final part of row to a new number created by multiplying the existing value with a floating point number.

`Row[8]` of the CSV file returns a string that is represented either as an `int`, `NaN` or `float`. I've replaced the `NaN`, found out about slicing to limit the string to 5 characters. Then I've tried to use a conditional that will convert the appropriate string into either an `int` or a `float`.

The final part of the for loop, I am trying to multiply the appropriate part of the CSV file by a float (1.98) and this is where I get the error (`TypeError: can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'float'`). If I change this to 2 i.e. an `int` the script runs.

I feel like the problem must exist in the conversion from string using the `if else` to either `int` or `float` but i'm not sure where. Any hints would be appreciated.

```
for row in csv_f:
        row[8] = row[8][:5]
        if isinstance(row[8], float):
            row[8] = float(row[8])
        if isinstance(row[8], int):
            row[8] = int(row[8])
        row[8] = row[8] * 1.9
        print row[8]
```

Comment: `isinstance()` will never be true for either of these cases because `row[8]` is always a string. If you're confident in your data, you can use `'.' in row[8]` as a test for a floating number instead.

Comment: Multiplying by an int works because you are multiplying the instance of the string. In your case, if you have `"9.99"` in the row value and it is multiplied by integer 2, it becomes `"9.999.99"`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your code, neither of

```
    if isinstance(row[8], float):
        row[8] = float(row[8])
    if isinstance(row[8], int):
        row[8] = int(row[8])
```

will be executed, as `row[8]` is of type `string`.

What you need to do is to simply change it to `row[8] = float(row[8])` and it will be OK.

Comment: I advise to add a safeguard: `if... elif... else: raise TypeError("value (%s) is unexpectedly of type \`%s'"%(row[8],type(row[8])))` This is a good general practice (manifestation of the principle "better safe than sorry"): always make the code choke when something happens that should never do. (also note the quotes around values: they help to see leading/trailing space)

Answer (score 0):

`row[8]` is a string

```
type(row[8])
<class 'str'>
```

Condition `if isinstance` is never executed.

Why when You change to `2` then work? Because `'a' * 2 == 'aa'`